# Кто работал с эквайрингом Тинькофф? Нужна помощь в получении нотификации об оплате

Tags: php, интернет-эквайринг

В нотификации об оплате указываю скрипт с следующим содержанием

```
<?
$tinkoff_confirm = $_POST;
$confirm_text_string = implode(';',$tinkoff_confirm);
$fp = fopen('tinkoff.txt','w');
fwrite($fp,$confirm_text_string);
fclose($fp);
echo ('OK');
?>
```

Платежи проходят, но в файл tinkoff.txt ничего не пишется, хотя с самописной формы этот скрипт работает. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, Тинькофф отправляет POST в формате JSON и его надо декодить.
Надеюсь этот скрипт поможет кому-нибудь.

```
<?
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$confirm_text_string = $data["OrderId"];
$fp = fopen('tinkoff.txt','w');
fwrite($fp,$confirm_text_string);
fclose($fp);
echo ('OK');
?>
```